# Issues with multiline button texts ignoring button margins

Tags: java, android, button, margin, line-breaks

Basically I have a button with a pretty long string which causes a line-break. The button has margins left and right which are however ignored with such multi line button texts as the button takes up the full width of the parent.

An obvious solution is to set the layout width to 0dp which however forces a static width meaning for a shorter buttontext the button is no longer wrapped.

Is there a good solution how to keep wrap_content for the width but still not have the margins ignored?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="@string/longstring"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line in the button xml so that the button respects the margins

```
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: That's the thing I was looking for. Follow-up question: How you can get exact wrapping as the automatic linebreak might not need the full width but still uses it?

Comment: glad i could help:)

Comment: using android:layout_width="match_parent" might help

Comment: Unfortunately that only increases the width of smaller buttons to the full width available.

Comment: then i have not understood the question correctly. Please try to be more elaborative.

Comment: With the current setup you will always use the full width when a linebreak happens (within the constraints). However after a linebreak the text width of each line can be smaller than with full width and in this case I still want to have the button wrapped in regards to the text. To give an example: you have 2 words taking up 55% of the available width, so you will get a linebreak as they don't fit in a single line. With the linebreak the background however uses the full 100% width and not 55% which would be possible if the text is wrapped properly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest of the solution is that you must use /n in your string in the button to make the button text not extend
For example "This is a string then /n It will be on the next line"

In this way I think your button will not ignore the margin and display the text inside

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:text="@string/longstring"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```